# Witharrows does not respect color

Tags: color, witharrows

I am using `witharrows` package and it seems like it does not respect surrounding color.

A sample code like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
    {\color{red}
 $\begin{WithArrows}
 A & = \bigl((a+b)+1\bigr)^2 \Arrow{}\Arrow{}[jump=2] \\
   & = (a+b)^2 + 2(a+b) +1 \\
   & = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 + 2a + 2b +1
\end{WithArrows}$
}
\end{document}
```

will produce the following
[image]

Is there any way to enforce the `WithArrows` environment to respect the surrounding color? Thanks.

Edit: Seems like compiling with `pdflatex` works fine; but I am not sure why `xelatex` will experience this (or, any pointer on how to debug this since in the comment someone can produce all red environment using `xelatex`)

I use manjaro.
My xelatex is (output of `xelatex --version`)

```
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 71.1; using 71.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.12; using 1.2.12
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.12.0; using 2.12.1
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 4.2.0; using 5.2.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.38
Compiled with pplib version v2.05 less toxic i hope
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.14.0; using 2.14.0
```

and packages I installed are the latest in the channel

```
texlive-bin 2022.62885-1
texlive-core 2022.63035-1
texlive-fontsextra 2022.62977-1
texlive-langchinese 2022.62922-1
texlive-langjapanese 2022.63011-1
texlive-latexextra 2022.63034-1
texlive-local-collection-fontsextra 63936-1
texlive-pictures 2022.62992-1
texlive-science 2022.62977-1
```

Comment: Your syntax is faulty: the `\color` macro takes 1 argument, not 2. Hence, instead of `\color{red}{...}`, do write `{\color{red}...}` in order to delimit the scope of the `\color` directive.

Comment: @Mico, thanks! I guess I was using it wrong the whole time! But fixing this produce the same though.

Comment: Please check your log file for information about the version of the `witharrows` package you employ. I use MacTeX2022, with all updates applied, and I find `witharrows 2022/04/20 v2.7` in the log file. FWIW, when I run your code, all three rows are red, and not just the first one.

Comment: @Mico, I checked my `.log` and it seems that I am using the same version too. Interestingly I still have the same output. I am using XeLatex, maybe this will change something? I updated my entire `.tex` file in the quesiton.

Comment: Even when using `witharrows` 2019/02/20 v1.15 and XeLaTeX, I don't get the output you show. All three lines are red in the result of my compilation. I cannot reproduce your output at all using the code you provide in your updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @JasperHabicht, somehow I can make the whole environment red with `pdflatex` but not `xelatex`. Honestly, I don't know how it could happen...

Comment: You should try to update your TeX installation.

Comment: @F.Pantigny thanks for your reply! I took an hour today to update my entire tex packages. I have edited the question to list the packages I had in my system. However updating seems to not fix the problem.

Comment: (I'm the author of the package `witharrows`). At this time, I have no solution (and no explanation) to your problem. You should send me by mail (my address is in the documentation of `witharrows`) your file *and the corresponding log file*. I will try to find a solution.

Comment: @F.Pantigny thank you! I will send you an email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mr. Pantigny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/163000/f-pantigny) helped me resolve this issue. Turns out that even though packages say "version 2022.xxx" on [manjaro channel](https://packages.manjaro.org/), they are **not the latest** versions. I have to install [vanilla texlive](https://tug.org/texlive/) and then, with the latest 2022 version, the problem got resolved.